# How to add "view in browser" and "forward to friend" in an email

Tags: html, email

I'm creating an html email, and I want to add these features:

- View in Browser

  - generates a link to the online version of the email
- Forward to Friend

  - opens mail forwarding dialogue

MailChimp has these features built in and I'd like to mimic their functionality.

How could I generate links that do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to host this HTML page somewhere in a server (website) and in your email point the link to this HTML page.

Comment: This is wrong. What about multipart/alternative with text/plain and text/html and the content types!

Comment: @amitchd He is asking about "View in browser" link that  you see in HTML emails. He used to host it with mailchip which is an online email marketing service provider. he is no longer going to use it and if the wants this option then I can't think about any other option. or did I understand the question wrong? :)

Comment: @Shoban No I understood it wrong ;).

Comment: i'm try to host it in my server..and it seem works rite now..but is there any other way to do it..it just one page of html..but how can i forward to friend

Comment: You can attach this HTML page (if it does not have any assets) along with the email.

Comment: Then I cant think of any other option.